# Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4 conversion

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

What is the equivalent code of Bootstrap 3

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
```

into Bootstrap 4 ?

Answer (score 1):

### Bootstrap 3 or Bootstrap 4 difference

> This is my article on this topic you can see here as well.
>
> link:
>   https://www.includehelp.com/html/difference-between-bootstrap-3-and-bootstrap-4.aspx
>
> you can see here as well
>
> link: http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/

### Bootstrap 3.x                 Bootstrap 4

```
.col-*-offset-*           .offset-*
.col-*-push-*             .order-*-2
.col-*-pull-*             .order-*-1
.panel                    .card
.panel-heading            .card-header
.panel-title              .card-title
.panel-body               .card-body
.panel-footer             .card-footer
.panel-primary            .card.bg-primary.text-white
.panel-success            .card.bg-success.text-white
.panel-info               .card.text-white.bg-info
.panel-warning            .card.bg-warning
.panel-danger             .card.bg-danger.text-white
.well                     .card.card-body
.thumbnail                .card.card-body
.list-inline > li         .list-inline-item
.dropdown-menu > li       .dropdown-item
.nav navbar > li          .nav-item
.nav navbar > li > a       .nav-link
.navbar-right             .ml-auto
.navbar-btn               .nav-item
.navbar-fixed-top         .fixed-top
.nav-stacked              .flex-column
.btn-default              .btn-secondary
.img-responsive           .img-fluid
.img-circle               .rounded-circle
.img-rounded              .rounded
.form-horizontal           (removed)
.radio                    .form-check
.checkbox                 .form-check
.input-lg                 .form-control-lg
.input-sm                 .form-control-sm
.control-label            .col-form-label
.table-condensed          .table-sm
.pagination > li          .page-item
.pagination > li > a      .page-link
.item                     .carousel-item
.help-block               .form-text
.pull-right               .float-right
.pull-left                .float-left
.center-block             .mx-auto.d-block
.hidden-xs                .d-none
.hidden-sm                .d-sm-none
.hidden-md                .d-md-none
.hidden-lg                .d-lg-none
.visible-xs               .d-block.d-sm-none
.visible-sm               .d-none.d-sm-block.d-md-none
.visible-md               .d-none.d-md-block.d-lg-none
.visible-lg               .d-none.d-lg-block.d-xl-none
.label                    .badge
.badge                    .badge.badge-pill
```

Answer (score 0):

### Equivalent code of Bootstrap 3

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
```

### Equivalent code of Bootstrap 4

> Try this it works on extra small device, ipad,ipad pro and laptop as
> well as extra large device

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
```

Comment: There is only col-12  See https://www.kasthuriwebdesign.com/what-is-the-simplest-way-of-converting-bootstrap-3-to-bootstrap-4/

Comment: If you put col-12 only then it will work for all device's. That's why i am using col-xs-12 only for extra small device. If you want to change column div size on large device then you have to use col-lg-* and if you want to set col-12 same size for all device then you can use only col-* class.